# How to edit shopify checkout page(checkout.liquid)

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

**I have basic subscription store in which i want to edit checkout page(html )**

Comment: add some code so it will be easy to solve the problem for us

Comment: Hi mukesh, have a look at these articles:  
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/checkout-style 
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/using-themes/change-the-layout/theme-code  
If you have problem with particular bit of code, show us what you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: @AnkitMahadik, thanks for your response i want to change the layout of checkout page such its header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

Only Shopify Plus members have the option to modify the `checkout.liquid` file.

Refer to: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/layouts/checkout

> The checkout.liquid asset is available to Shopify Plus merchants only. If your store isn't on Shopify Plus, then you can customize your checkout pages in the theme editor.

Comment: Hey @drip, can we customize header and footer of checkout page?

Comment: @mukesh You can customize only what is in the Theme Customisation Panel (logo/color/fonts etc..). You can't modify any html if you are not PLUS member.